# Show values matching multiple statements

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck about how to move forward with this problem.

I have a Excel sheet looking like the attached images. What I want to do is in another sheet present all reviews that have a comment attached.

What I want to do is that in the Sheet(Report) I want to show a list consisting of all Good/Bad scores connected to team A during week 42 where a comment has been made.
So in this example the list would be concisting of row 2 and 4.

[image]

The source list consist of over 100k rows so for my first try was to limit the formula with offset to look only on the rows in the specified week. But maybe vba code is a better quicker way to do this?

Comment: There is no *nice* way to do this. I would suggest just using filters to access the data you need - otherwise it's a fairly sizeable VBA project

Comment: To add to CallumDA33's suggestion, why not convert your data to a table and filter will automatically be added, as well as formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim row As Integer, lastrow As Long, rng As Range

'This filters the data and copies the result to a second worksheet - Sheet2 (rename to suit)

With Sheet1

    On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    .Range("A1:D" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="a"
    .Range("A1:D" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="42"
    .Range("A1:D" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"

        Set rng = .Range("A1:D" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

         If rng.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row > 1 Then ' If Not just header row visible  i.e your filter has some actual results

            Set rng = .Range("A2:D" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'A2 to exclude header
            rng.Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1) 'Copy to next available row in sheet 2

         End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have said that I can't use filter in this report. The raw data is used in multiple sheets so trying to filter the data triggers a recalculation that kills the computer.

Comment: Ok, ill use a different method and post it later

Answer (score 0):

I finally did find a function that manage to do what I wanted.

This code shows the data in the 7th column. By changing the 7 at the end of the formula I can choose to show the columns I want to have and then just copy the formula all the way down as far as I need.

If anyone use this code don't forget it's an array, after you put it in Excel instead of pressing enter you have to press ctrl+shift+enter.

```
`=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw ticket'!$1:$1048576;
SMALL(
IF((44='Raw ticket'!M:M)*(1='Raw ticket'!H:H)*("a"='Raw ticket'!C:C)*(ISTEXT('Raw ticket'!G:G)); ROW('Raw ticket'!A:A)-ROW('Raw ticket'!$A$2)+2); ROW(1:1));7);"")`
```